# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el resultado de una función de JavaScript en otra página HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, funciones

Tengo una pequeña duda: Tengo el siguiente código en mi página index:

```html
<body>
    Nombre: <input id="nombre">
    <button id="say"><a href="inicio.html">Enviar</a></button>
    <hr>
    <div id="result">
 <script src="funciones.js">
 function say_hi();
 </script>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Esta página está enlazada a un documento JavaScript con la siguiente función:

```
function say_hi() {
var name = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
var res = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1).toLowerCase();
var html = '<b>' + res + '</b>' + ' ' +'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'; 
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
}
document.getElementById('say').addEventListener('click', say_hi);
```

Necesito  que cuando se de click en el botón enviar el resultado se muestre en mi segunda página denominada inicio.html y no se como puedo hacer esto,  les agradezco mucho su ayuda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías utilizar `localStorage`, de momento es compatible con casi todos los navegadores modernos (exceptuando Opera Mini):

[image: Sacado de CanIUse.com]

La forma de utilizarlo es la siguiente:

```
localStorage.setItem('llave', 'valor'); // Añadimos un nuevo registro
localStorage.getItem('llave'); // Obtenemos un registro existente
localStorage.removeItem('llave'); // Eliminamos un registro existente
localStorage.clear(); // Borramos todos los registros
```

Ejemplo Básico:

```
<input value="0" id="test"> <button id="plus">+</button>

var $inp = $("#test"),
$btn = $("#plus"),
$val = localStorage.getItem('testp') ? localStorage.getItem('testp') : $inp.val();

$inp.on("click", function() {
  $val += 1;  
  $inp.val($val);
  localStorage.setItem('testp', $val);
});
```

Información Adicional (*en ingles*):

- https://alligator.io/js/introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage/
- https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/

Información Adicional (*en español*):

- https://platzi.com/blog/local-storage-html5/

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Jesus, veo que esta es la mejor opcion pero aun tengo la duda de como hacer para que pueda llamar el resultado desde mi segunda pagina: inicio.html

Comment: En tu primera página, donde lo necesites según lo que quieras hacer, colocas `localStorage.setItem('llave', 'valor');` y en tu segunda página donde lo necesites utilizas `localStorage.getItem('llave');`. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias, Jesus, una ultima duda el codigo de la funciond ebe estar en mi primera pagina o en un archivo .js?

Comment: Es indiferente, puedes colocarlo en una etiqueta `<script>` en tu página o bien en un archivo `.js`. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Para ello puedes redirigir a la otra página con un parámetro, por ejemplo, en el primer archivo:

```
window.location.href("inicio.html?sayhi=true");
```

Y en el archivo `incio.html`:

```
//Tomamos la string de la URL y creamos un objeto URL
var url_string = "http://www.example.com/inicio.html?sayhi=true"; 
var url = new URL(url_string);
//Tomamos el valor del parámetro y lo almacenamos en una variable
var ejecutarFuncion = url.searchParams.get("sayhi");
if(ejecutarFuncion) {
  //La funcion sayhi iría aqui
}
```

Comment: disculpa tengo una duda el window.location.href("inicio.html?sayhi=true"); en que parte lo coloco?

Comment: En el archivo en el que quieras redireccionar, esa funcion lo que hace es redirigirte a la pagina que quieras, por ejemplo: `window.location.href("google.es");` te redireccionará a google